# No route matches [Delete] "/months.5"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm kind of new in Rails and I'm having a problem with the routes. When I try to delete a control there's an error that says 'No route matches [DELETE] "/months.5". And I dont know why. I show you my code.

Ruotes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

      root 'staticpages#index'

      devise_for :users # :path => '',

     #  path_names: {sign_in: 'login', sign_up: 'registro'},
     # controllers: {sessiones: 'users/controls'}

      get '/controls/calendar' => 'controls#event'

      get 'graphicscontrols' => 'graphics#graphics_evolution'

      get 'months' => 'controls#months'

      # resources :users, only: [:show]  do #:path => '' 
      resources :controls # :path => '' 
      resources :graphics, only: [:index]


      resources :meals, only: [:index, :new, :create]
```

Controls Controller

class ControlsController < ApplicationController

```
before_action :authenticate_user!

def index



    @user= current_user
    @control= Control.new

    @control_last= @user.controls.last

    @controls= @user.controls.order_by_date

    @controls_average = Control.controls_average (current_user.id)

    @controls_average_day = Control.controls_day_average (current_user.id)
    # @controls = Control.order_by_date
end

def event
    @user= current_user
    @controls=@user.controls.all
    render json: @controls if request.xhr?
end

def months
    @user= current_user
    @controls= @user.controls.order_by_date
end

def create
    @user = current_user
    control_params2 ={}
    control_params2[:level] = control_params[:level]
    control_params2[:period] = control_params[:period]
    control_params2[:day]=DateTime.strptime(control_params[:day],'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
    @control= @user.controls.build(control_params2)
    @control.save!
    flash[:notice] = "Congratulations, your control has been created"
    redirect_to controls_path
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    render 'index'
end


def edit
    @control = Control.find(params[:id])

end


def update
    @user = current_user
    @control = Control.find(params[:id])
    if @control.update_attributes(control_params)
        flash[:notice] = "Congratulations, your control has been updated"
        redirect_to controls_path(current_user)
    else
        @errors = @control.errors.full_messages
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def delete
    @control= Control.find(params[:id])

end

def destroy
    @control= Control.find(params[:id])
    if @control.delete
        flash[:notice] = "Congratulations, your control has been removed"
        redirect_to months_path
    end
end
private
def control_params
    params.require(:control).permit(:level, :period, :day)
end
```

end

views/controls/moonths.html.erb

```
<h1>Controls</h1>

<ul>
  <% @controls.each do |control| %>
    <li><%= "Blood Sugar Control:" + control.level.to_s + " - " + control.period + " - " +     control.day.to_s %></li>
    <%= link_to "Delete", months_path(control), method:'delete', data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
    <%= link_to "edit", edit_control_path(control)%>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check `rake routes` once, you will understand more on routes

Now you can do is

```
<%= link_to "Delete", control, method:'delete', data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
```

or also

```
<%= link_to "Delete", control_path(control.id), method:'delete', data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
```

You are deleting Control object use control_path(..), or for Month object use month_path(..)

Comment: Ok, if I put control_path(control.id) it works, but what I want is that when I click on delete it redirects me to month_path. But if i write month_path(control.id) it says No route matches [DELETE] "/controls.20"

Comment: do `month_path(id: control.id)`

Answer (score -1):

In your view you should put this

```
<h1>Controls</h1>

<ul>
  <% @controls.each do |control| %>
    <li><%= "Blood Sugar Control:" + control.level.to_s + " - " + control.period + " - " +     control.day.to_s %></li>
    <%= link_to "Delete", controls_path(control), method:'delete', data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
    <%= link_to "edit", edit_control_path(control)%>
</ul>
<% end %>
```